# How do I give stdin for a program without a separate file?

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I have a program, but I do not have access to the code. The program reads stdin. A typical invocation looks like this --

```
> ./.prog
> input-1: <I give input-1>
> input-2: <I give input-2>
.
.
.
> input-n: <I give input-n>
> output
```

What I am doing now is putting all the arguments in a file called `argsfile.in`, the contents are like this --

```
input-1
input-1
...
input-n
```

and call it --

> ./prog < argsfile.in

I want to do the same thing without using a file, something like this --

`>./prog < "input-1" "input_2" ... "input-3"`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution is a ["here document"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents):

```
./prog <<"END"
input-1
input-2
input-3
...
END
```

You can use any string instead of `END`. If you want to include parameter expansions, etc. in the input, use `END` instead of `"END"`.

In `bash`, you can also use a ["here string"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings):

```
./prog <<< $'input-1\ninput-2\ninput-3'
```

With the help of `printf` and command substitution, you can make that more readable:

```
./prog <<< "$(printf %s\\n "input-1" "input-2" "input-3")"
```

That version is handy if you have the various input lines in an array, for example:

```
./prog <<< "$(printf %s\\n "${files[@]}")"
```